# How to restore "Create new folder..." in context menu of windows

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu, restore

I now experimented with windows registry, but I deleted a "Create new folder..." from the context menu. Now, I have a little problem; in which registry hive is this point stored? I want to restore "Create new folder..."

Comment: And the programming question is?

Comment: I wrote my program, which accidentally deleted this key. I need address of this key at windows registry. I think, that it is question about programming too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is mostly not for developer. Nevertheless the part of registry which are responsible to create a folder you will find here:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew
```

It is of course not the only part which you could delete/rename to make the corresponding item in the context menu disappear. I general `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` part is the place which mostly responsible for the problem which you try to solve. It you want to examine your problem more exactly the [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) could be helpful for you. You should have a little experience in setting of filters to reduce the output which you need to analyse.

Answer (score 0):

I Assume that you did not backup the registry before that :)

I suggest to find some good dedicated tool

Here there is some information about managing the Context Menu Entries:

http://windowsxp.mvps.org/context_folders.htm

Doing it manually will be extremely hard ?